# What is the difference between javascript and DOJO. Is it interdependent?

Tags: ibm-case-manager

I have been using DOJO in Case manager. Do we really need to use DOJO for customization. The coding is similar to Javascript. Is the any relation between DOJO and javascript. What is the difference

Answer (score 1):

Dojo (or more formally Dojo Toolkit) is a framework for developing JavaScript applications similiar to React or Vue.js.

It is (or least was) the framework of choice by IBM for the Web UI development for their Enterprise Content Management/Digital Business Automation (at least for IBM Content Navigator, Case Manager, FileNet and the IBM Content Collector for SAP UIs).

It provides reusable general components (Widgets) for UI and in the case of the Case Manager specialized Widgets to work with the Case Manager system (such as the data model etc).

While customizing and extending Case Manager you write JavaScript with some syntax for class/module loading specific to the Dojo Toolkit.

So there is really no difference between using JavaScript or the Dojo Toolkit.

As for the question if you have to use the Dojo Toolkit, the answer must be yes, although sometimes you will get away with vanilla JavaScript, but most of the time you will need to use the Dojo Toolkit (or the JavaScript libraries provided by IBM Case Manager).

At least for the IBM Content Navigator there is some ongoing effort to integrate React respectively replace the Dojo Toolkit with React. But I doubt, that this will happen anytime soon, especially for Case Manager.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info